# How to copy Maven build artifact from a sub-module target to the parent target?

Tags: java, maven, multi-module, artifact

There is a modular Maven project with several modules (3 in this example) that somehow depend on each other.
Here is the root project pom (nothing special):

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <description>Root project for modules build</description>
  <groupId>abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>modules/first</module>
    <module>modules/second</module>
    <module>modules/third</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

After building the root project (`mvn package`) we got three artifacts accordingly in the "target" folders

```
%rootdir%/modules/first/target/artifact_1.jar
%rootdir%/modules/second/target/artifact_2.jar
%rootdir%/modules/third/target/artifact_3.jar
```

I would like to copy `artifact_3.jar` into `%rootdir%/target/main_artifact.jar` to emphasize that the target of the whole build is this `jar` file.

I know how to copy a file into a particular folder, but this "imperative" copying seems to be an unconventional action breaking the abstraction of Maven.

**What is the proper way to put the artifact `main_artifact.jar` into the right place `%rootdir%/target/`?**
*Presumingly there must be a configuration to add into `%rootdir%/pom.xml`. I'll be thankful if you share a standard Maven approach to do that.*

Comment: Why do you have an intermediate level in your project? Why not removing the `modules` directory ? Or maybe better create a pom file in `modules` directory which contains the other three modules... Apart from that why is it needed to copy that artifact into a different position?

Comment: Too many questions bringing us nowhere (to the position "it is not what we are accustomed to"). I have the `modules` directory, because this organization of the project serves other purposes of the project maintenance not related to the question. Assume we have removed `modules` and got the same three modules one level upper. What would have changed then? Copying the artifact is not "needed" - it is possible to leave the things as they are. The only goal is to declare the intention, as I say above "emphasize the target of the whole build"

Comment: First if you don't think that questions don't help? Ok..it's up to you. So the simple answer to this is: The right place of artifacts is the `target` directory of the appropriate module that's it. Copying is not possible neither useful. The root directory make absolute no sense because the root module is of packaging `pom` which means it does not produce anything...Based on your denial to answer questions... I can not help anymore...

Answer (score -2):

In Maven you don't copy artifacts from one target to the other.

You build them in their respective target directories, and then you install them into the local repository and/or deploy them onto a Maven repository (like Nexus or Artifactory).

So there is no Maven way to copy artifacts from one target to the other because you just don't do it.